# How do I process WM_SETTEXT message

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to redraw NC area of the window and set custom text in there. So with redrawing I'm okay, but I don't know what should I use to set my own text in caption of the window. I tried to use `DefWindowProc` function, but it suddenly draws default windows title bar, which is unnecessarily. Using `SetWindowText` also is inappropriate, because it causes `WM_SETTEXT` message once again. So help me, please, I need just to customize caption of window without any drawing default title bar.

```
LRESULT SkinWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam)
{
    ...
    case WM_SETTEXT:
      OnSetText(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
    break;
    ...
}

void SkinWindow::OnSetText(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, wParam, lParam);
    OnNcPaint(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have your own WM_NCPAINT handliner (OnNcPaint) draw the text?  That is, swallow WM_SETTEXT, remember the text it was trying to specify, and then use that string for all subsequent WM_NCPAINT callbacks.

Comment: Maybe. But how could I mark that sting as a window caption, so that it will be able to use functions like GetWindowText and GetWindowTextLength? If I use SetWindowText it causes WM_SETTEXT again.

Comment: Store text somewhere in skin window class.

Comment: So, i will have to listen and customize all messages related with that caption? WM_GETTEXT, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, WM_SETTEXT, do window have a lot of these?

Answer (score 0):

You must fully handle the [two gettext messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833):

```
case WM_GETTEXT:
    lstrcpyn((LPTSTR)lParam, "Booga!", (int)wParam);
    return lstrlen((LPTSTR)lParam);
case WM_GETTEXTLENGTH: 
    return 7; // lstrlen("Booga!") + null
```

If you want `WM_SETTEXT` to work correctly you must store the text in you own buffer and use that buffer when queried for the text. Never pass these to `DefWindowProc` because `DefWindowProc` stores/retrieves the text internally in the `HWND`.

Note: External applications will still read it incorrectly if they use `GetWindowText` because it reads from the hidden internal storage when sent cross-process.